# perl array for non-zero values

Tags: perl

Im trying to code a "service" script based on "ps".
my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
die "usage:    $0 <service name>\n" unless $ARGV[0];
my $service = $ARGV[0];
open(my $ps, "ps -aux |") || die "Uknown command\n";
my @A = <$ps>;
close $ps;
foreach my $i(grep /$service/, @A){
    chomp $i;
    if($i=~ /root/){
        next
    }
    print "$i\n";
}
```

My problem: When running the script against undef arg like:

```
$0 blablabla
```

I want to return an output if there is  no such service appears/when returns 0
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you are asking is: How to give a proper message when no matching lines are found?

Well, just store the result in an array instead:

```
my @lines = grep { !/root/ && /$service/ } @A;

if (@lines) {   # if any lines are found
    for my $line (@lines) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    print "No match for '$service'!\n";
}
```

Or you can print the number of matches regardless of their number:

```
my $found = @lines;
print "Matched found: $found\n";
```

Note also that you can add the check for root in your grep.

As a side note, this part:

```
die "usage:    $0 <service name>\n" unless $ARGV[0];
my $service = $ARGV[0];
```

Is perhaps better written

```
my $service = shift;
die "usage ...." unless defined $service;
```

Which specifically checks if the argument is defined or not, as opposed to true or not.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to inform the user if no such service was found? If so, you can modify the script as follows:

```
my $printed;                        # Will be used as a flag.
foreach my $i(grep /$service/, @A){
    chomp $i;
    if($i=~ /root/){
        next
    }
    $printed = print "$i\n";        # Set the flag if the service was found.
}
warn "No service found\n" unless $printed;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
my @processes = grep /$service/, @A;
if ( scalar @processes ) {
    foreach my $i( @processes ){
        chomp $i;
        if($i=~ /root/){
            next;
        }
        print "$i\n";
    }
}
else {
    print 'your message';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the result of the `grep` command before traversing it in the `for` loop, like:

```
...

my @services = grep { m/$service/ } @A;

# Filter the perl process running this script and...
if ( ! @services ) { 
    print "No service found\n";
    exit 0;
}

foreach my $i( @services ){
    ...
}
```

Take into account that the `grep` command will never give a false return because it is including the `perl` process, so you will have to filter it, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I got it. This is actually the  logical way, however my code  [not posted here] didn't work. Thanks